# How to avoid sub-stacks being squeezed onto the baseline?

Tags: math-mode, xetex, subscripts

**I'm using XeLaTeX on Linux** *(just to pre-empt any questions about that...)*

I think my question is best described with this Picture:

[image]

As you can see in the red circles, the `n \to \infty` line got squeezed onto the baseline when  `\lim` is used inside something like `\frac{}{}`, here's the relevant code portion:

```
    &=& \lim_{n \to \infty} - \frac{1}{n} \frac{c^{\frac{1}{n}}(c-1)}{c^{\frac{1}{n}} - 1} \\
    &=& - \frac{\lim_{n \to \infty} c^{\frac{1}{n}} (c-1)}
               {\lim_{n \to \infty} n \left(c^{\frac{1}{n}}-1\right)} \*(the portion is inside an `eqnarray*` environment)*
```

It should be evident, that in both instances, `\lim` has the same parameters, but behaves differently.

How do I avaid that line being squeezed over next to `\lim` rather than below it?

On a lesser note: I'd like to give my exponents a bit more headroom (blue circles), make them smaller maybe or something. Please advice what I should do.

Comment: Display style: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/LaTeX:Math#Display_Style_.28.5Cdisplaystyle.29 or `\limits`: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics#Limits

Comment: And please do stop using `eqnarray`, see http://tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/madsen/

Comment: So... I gather from the article, that I should use `align` and `equation` instead... OK, I will do that in the future. I already turned the assignment in, as you've probably assumed. When making fractions in nested cases, I should just use slashes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three problems in your input.

1. Never use `eqnarray`.
2. It's better not to use fractions in exponents.
3. In this particular case, `\lim\limits` seems justified.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} - \frac{1}{n} \frac{c^{1/n}(c-1)}{c^{1/n} - 1} \\
&= - \frac{\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} c^{1/n} (c-1)}
          {\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} n (c^{1/n}-1)}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]